# Google Analytics Multi-Channel Funnels connection c#

Tags: c#, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm trying to retrieve the first/last/assisted interactions from Multi-Channel Funnels Reporting API. I can't seem to figure out how to connect to the API in C#. 
I do already have a working connection with the Core Reporting API. Any help/ working examples would be appreciated.

> UPDATE --> working code (for me)

```
public class MCFHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns Analytics Multi-Channel Funnels data for a view (profile). 
    /// Documentation https://developers.google.com/analytics/v3/reference/mcf/get
    /// Generation Note: This does not always build corectly.  Google needs to standardise things I need to figuer out which ones are wrong.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="service">Authenticated Analytics service.</param>  
    /// <param name="ids">Unique table ID for retrieving Analytics data. Table ID is of the form ga:XXXX, where XXXX is the Analytics view (profile) ID.</param>
    /// <param name="start-date">Start date for fetching Analytics data. Requests can specify a start date formatted as YYYY-MM-DD, or as a relative date (e.g., today, yesterday, or 7daysAgo). The default value is 7daysAgo.</param>
    /// <param name="end-date">End date for fetching Analytics data. Requests can specify a start date formatted as YYYY-MM-DD, or as a relative date (e.g., today, yesterday, or 7daysAgo). The default value is 7daysAgo.</param>
    /// <param name="metrics">A comma-separated list of Multi-Channel Funnels metrics. E.g., 'mcf:totalConversions,mcf:totalConversionValue'. At least one metric must be specified.</param>
    /// <param name="optional">Optional paramaters.</param>
    /// <returns>McfDataResponse</returns>
    public static McfData Get(AnalyticsService service, string ids, string startdate, string enddate, string metrics, McfGetOptionalParms optional = null)
    {
        try
        {
            // Initial validation.
            if (service == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("service");
            if (ids == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(ids);
            if (startdate == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(startdate);
            if (enddate == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(enddate);
            if (metrics == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(metrics);

            // Building the initial request.
            var request = service.Data.Mcf.Get(ids, startdate, enddate, metrics);



            // Applying optional parameters to the request.                
            request = (McfResource.GetRequest)SampleHelpers.ApplyOptionalParms(request, optional);
            // Requesting data.
            var result = request.Execute();

            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Request Mcf.Get failed.", ex);
        }
    }

    public static McfData ImportMcfData(string accessToken, GoogleAnalyticsApi.GoogleAnalyticsClientApi client)
    {
        MCFHelper.McfSample.McfGetOptionalParms dimensions = new MCFHelper.McfSample.McfGetOptionalParms();
        dimensions.Dimensions = ""; <-- insert dimensions
        var metrics = ""; <-- insert metrics
        var service = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
        {
            ApplicationName = "",
            HttpClientInitializer = new CustomUserCredential(accessToken)
        });

        string ids = "ga:"; <-- insert viewId
        var data = MCFHelper.Get(service, ids, "2018-10-15", "today", metrics, dimensions);

        return data;
    }

    public static class McfSample
    {
        public class McfGetOptionalParms
        {
            /// A comma-separated list of Multi-Channel Funnels dimensions. E.g., 'mcf:source,mcf:medium'.
            public string Dimensions { get; set; }
            /// A comma-separated list of dimension or metric filters to be applied to the Analytics data.
            public string Filters { get; set; }
            /// The maximum number of entries to include in this feed.
            public string Metrics { get; set; }

        }
    }
    public static class SampleHelpers
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Using reflection to apply optional parameters to the request.  
        /// 
        /// If the optonal parameters are null then we will just return the request as is.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="request">The request. </param>
        /// <param name="optional">The optional parameters. </param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static object ApplyOptionalParms(object request, object optional)
        {
            if (optional == null)
                return request;

            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] optionalProperties = (optional.GetType()).GetProperties();

            foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property in optionalProperties)
            {
                // Copy value from optional parms to the request.  They should have the same names and datatypes.
                System.Reflection.PropertyInfo piShared = (request.GetType()).GetProperty(property.Name);
                if (property.GetValue(optional, null) != null) // TODO Test that we do not add values for items that are null
                    piShared.SetValue(request, property.GetValue(optional, null), null);
            }

            return request;
        }
    }
}
```

Blockquote

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you are currently using.  You are aware that the Core reporting api is not the same as the  [Multi channel funneling api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/authorization)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the only sample code i have for that api.  Remember its not the core reporting api its a separate api in and of itself.   The analytics service you have created though should work with these code.  Just make sure you have set the scopes corectly.

```
 public static class McfSample
    {

        public class McfGetOptionalParms
        {
            /// A comma-separated list of Multi-Channel Funnels dimensions. E.g., 'mcf:source,mcf:medium'.
            public string Dimensions { get; set; }  
            /// A comma-separated list of dimension or metric filters to be applied to the Analytics data.
            public string Filters { get; set; }  
            /// The maximum number of entries to include in this feed.
            public int? Max-results { get; set; }  
            /// The desired sampling level.
            public string SamplingLevel { get; set; }  
            /// A comma-separated list of dimensions or metrics that determine the sort order for the Analytics data.
            public string Sort { get; set; }  
            /// An index of the first entity to retrieve. Use this parameter as a pagination mechanism along with the max-results parameter.
            public int? Start-index { get; set; }  

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns Analytics Multi-Channel Funnels data for a view (profile). 
        /// Documentation https://developers.google.com/analytics/v3/reference/mcf/get
        /// Generation Note: This does not always build corectly.  Google needs to standardise things I need to figuer out which ones are wrong.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="service">Authenticated Analytics service.</param>  
        /// <param name="ids">Unique table ID for retrieving Analytics data. Table ID is of the form ga:XXXX, where XXXX is the Analytics view (profile) ID.</param>
        /// <param name="start-date">Start date for fetching Analytics data. Requests can specify a start date formatted as YYYY-MM-DD, or as a relative date (e.g., today, yesterday, or 7daysAgo). The default value is 7daysAgo.</param>
        /// <param name="end-date">End date for fetching Analytics data. Requests can specify a start date formatted as YYYY-MM-DD, or as a relative date (e.g., today, yesterday, or 7daysAgo). The default value is 7daysAgo.</param>
        /// <param name="metrics">A comma-separated list of Multi-Channel Funnels metrics. E.g., 'mcf:totalConversions,mcf:totalConversionValue'. At least one metric must be specified.</param>
        /// <param name="optional">Optional paramaters.</param>
        /// <returns>McfDataResponse</returns>
        public static McfData Get(AnalyticsService service, string ids, string start-date, string end-date, string metrics, McfGetOptionalParms optional = null)
        {
            try
            {
                // Initial validation.
                if (service == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("service");
                if (ids == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(ids);
                if (start-date == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(start-date);
                if (end-date == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(end-date);
                if (metrics == null)
                    throw new ArgumentNullException(metrics);

                // Building the initial request.
                var request = service.Mcf.Get(ids, start-date, end-date, metrics);

                // Applying optional parameters to the request.                
                request = (McfResource.GetRequest)SampleHelpers.ApplyOptionalParms(request, optional);

                // Requesting data.
                return request.Execute();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Request Mcf.Get failed.", ex);
            }
        }

        }

        public static class SampleHelpers
        {

        /// <summary>
        /// Using reflection to apply optional parameters to the request.  
        /// 
        /// If the optonal parameters are null then we will just return the request as is.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="request">The request. </param>
        /// <param name="optional">The optional parameters. </param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static object ApplyOptionalParms(object request, object optional)
        {
            if (optional == null)
                return request;

            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] optionalProperties = (optional.GetType()).GetProperties();

            foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property in optionalProperties)
            {
                // Copy value from optional parms to the request.  They should have the same names and datatypes.
                System.Reflection.PropertyInfo piShared = (request.GetType()).GetProperty(property.Name);
                if (property.GetValue(optional, null) != null) // TODO Test that we do not add values for items that are null
                    piShared.SetValue(request, property.GetValue(optional, null), null);
            }

            return request;
        }
    }
}
```

code ripped from [Mcf Sample](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Google%20Analytics%20API/v3/McfSampleData)

Comment: Thanks DalmTo, I had to tweak the code a little bit and add some extra code to get it work. Thanks for your help!